# Is it possible to use malloc for increasing the size of existing array?

Tags: c++, c

Please tell me, is it possible to use malloc for increasing the size of **existing** array? (without allocating a new array and then doing memcpy) If yes, how?

Comment: As yourself: How could that work if the space right next to the array is already allocated for something else?

Comment: @delnan see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9367362/901059 where I've already pointed out why this doesn't work.

Comment: @mydogisbox: I know, hence my suggestion to OP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [realloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/realloc.html). Note that it might change the address of the array, so be sure to assign the return value.

Comment: It might also return NULL if it can't resize the array, so you want to make sure to assign the return value to a *different* variable and test for NULL.

Comment: Indeed. Same applies for `malloc` - I wonder how many programs bother checking the return value of _that_.

Answer (score 4):

No, an array requires contiguous memory and there is no way to guarantee that the memory after the current allocation is free.  As @James McLaughlin pointed out, you can use realloc in place of creating a new array and then doing a memcopy, but it does essentially the same thing.

Comment: It seems, it does the same thing as malloc+memcpy only if the new size of the memory object would require movement of the object (e.g. if the close memory field is already occupied by some program). I work with small arrays (a few KBytes) so in most cases the movement wouldn't be required.

Comment: That's true, but I was addressing the specific question you were asking which involves increasing the size of the array, not simply allocating it to a new location.

Comment: If you're in c++ then I would recommend simply using the stl vector (assuming you don't have performance considerations that make this unworkable) since it handles the resizing for you in much the same fashion as realloc.